# I get compile errors: data_out is not a valid l-value

Tags: verilog, iverilog

1. This is the module unit...

   ```
   module register_unit(data_out,data_in,load,clk,rst);
   parameter word_size=8;
   output [word_size-1:0] data_out;
   input [word_size-1:0] data_in;
   input load,clk,rst;
   reg data_out;

   always@(posedge clk or negedge rst)
     if(rst==0)
       data_out <= 0;
     else if(load)
       data_out <= data_in;
   endmodule
   ```
2. This is the test bench

   ```
   `include "register_unit.v"

   module test_bench();

   parameter word_size=8;

   reg clk,rst,load;
   reg [word_size-1:0] data_in;
   wire [word_size-1:0] data_out;

   register_unit m1 (.data_out(data_out),.data_in(data_in),.load(load),.clk(clk),.rst(rst));

   initial
   begin
     clk=0;
     forever begin
       #5 clk = ! clk; 
     end
   end

   initial
   begin
     rst=0;
     data_out=8'b0;
     load=0;
     #10 rst=1;
     load=1;
     #10 data_out=8'b00000100;
     #10 data_out=8'b00000101;
     #20 load=0;
   end

   initial
   begin
     $dumpfile ("register_unit.vcd");
     $dumpvars;
   end
   endmodule
   ```
3. I am compiling this code using iverilog command in linux.
4. iverilog -o register_unit.v register_unit_tb.v
5. While compiling the code it gives an error on data_out port it says it is invalid conversion.
6. Errors are data_out is not a valid l-value in test_bench and data_out is declared here as wire.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to a `wire` in an `initial` block.  In the `initial` block in your testbench, change `data_out` to `data_in`:

```
initial
begin
rst=0;
data_in=8'b0;
load=0;
#10 rst=1;
load=1;
#10 data_in=8'b00000100;
#10 data_in=8'b00000101;
#20 load=0;
end
```

I also got a compiler warning in `register_unit`.  You should declare the `reg` using a bit width:

```
reg [word_size-1:0] data_out;
```

Comment: The compiler warning on `register_unit` could also be resolved by switching to ANSI style header.  `module register_unit #(parameter word_size=8) ( output reg [word_size-1:0] data_out, input [word_size-1:0] data_in, input load, clk, rst );`